# Prove $\sum_{b=0}^{n-1}b\binom{n+1-b}{2} = \binom{n+2}{4}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> An equilateral triangle of side $n$ is divided into $n^2$ equilateral
> triangles of side $1$ such that each side of the congruent triangles
> is parallel to the original triangle. Find the number of
> parallelograms that can be formed by the segments.

The answer to this problem is $3 \binom{n+2}{4}$. I have a different solution than the intended one and arrived at the following sum:
$$3\sum_{b=0}^{n-1}b\binom{n+1-b}{2}$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20b%20*%20binom%28n%2B1-b%2C2%29%2C%20b%3D0%20to%20n-1%20%3D%20binom%28n%2B2%2C4%29) verifies that it is equal to $3\binom{n+2}{4}$, however I can't prove it. I tried pairing the terms, applying some identities, but failed.

Comment: An a way is:
 $$3\sum_{b=1}^{n-1}b\binom{n+1-b}{2}=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{b=1}^{n-1}b^3-\frac{3}{2}(2n+1)\sum_{b=1}^{n-1}b^2+\frac{3}{2}(n^2+n)\sum_{b=1}^{n-1}b$$...

Answer (score 3):

I'll show bijectively that $$\sum_{b = 0}^{n-1} b \cdot \binom{n-1-b}{2} = \binom{n}{4}\,.$$

The right-hand side is clearly the number of ways to choose a subset of $4$ elements from $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.  We can choose this by

- Choosing the second largest element and calling it $n - b$
- Choosing the largest element, for which we have $b$ choices.
- Choosing the two smallest elements from the set $[n-b-1]$ for which we have $\binom{n-1-b}{2}$ choices.

This gives the formula for the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

**Marcus M** has given a very nice combinatorial proof, which in general I prefer. Here’s a computational proof, in case you’re more comfortable with that approach.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{b=0}^{n-1}b\binom{n-1-b}2&\overset{(0)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-1-k)\binom{k}2\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k}2-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)\binom{k}2\\
&\overset{(1)}=n\binom{n}3-3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}3\\
&=n\binom{n}3-3\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k}3\\
&\overset{(1)}=n\binom{n}3-3\binom{n+1}4\\
&=\frac{n^2(n-1)(n-2)}6-\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}8\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}2\left(\frac{n}3-\frac{n+1}4\right)\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}2\cdot\frac{n-3}{12}\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}\\
&=\binom{n}4\;.
\end{align*}$$

At $(0)$ I substituted $k=n-1-b$, and at $(1)$ I used the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).